# CPAN Dependency in Debian packaging

Tags: debian, packages, cpan

In Debian packaging (i.e. the debian/control file), is there a way to define dependencies to specific CPAN modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a Debian package for each CPAN module that you need, and declare those as dependencies. The Debian Perl policy (`/usr/share/doc/debian-policy/perl-policy.*`) has some information on that. The tool `dh-make-perl` automates most of the module packaging work.